# C++ ranges-v3 concepts::valid_expr checks, with trailing ", 42"

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, c++-concepts, comma-operator

Continuing my reading of ranges-v3 library, I realized that all of checks about valid expressions for template types has a tailing ", 42" expression, and I wonder what is the purpose of that. For example:

```
namespace concepts {
    constexpr struct valid_expr
    {
       template<typename... T>
       void operator()(T&&...) const;
    };
}

struct ExplicitlyConvertibleTo
{
   template<typename From, typename To>
   auto requires_(From (&from)()) -> decltype(
       concepts::valid_expr(
           ((void) static_cast<To>(from()), 42)
   ));
};
```

I understand some of the points of that implementation, like the inner parenthesis to force the use of the comma operator, the void-casting to avoid some overloads of the comma operator, etc, but why not just simply writting something like?

```
concepts::valid_expr(static_cast<To>(from()));
```

Comment: just a wild guess, can it be related with the fact that `concepts::valid_expr::operator()` returns `void`, and type of `(void, 42)` expression is `int`? e.g. to avoid two branches of some external code we don't see here that handles `void` case and non-void case?

Answer (score 5):

A small correction: In range-v3, `valid_expr` is an object not a type:

```
constexpr struct valid_expr_t { /*...*/ } valid_expr;
```

Now, consider what happens if you use `concepts::valid_expr(static_cast<To>(from()))` as suggested and `To` is `void`. It is allowable to `static_cast` to `void`, but it is not allowable to call a function with an argument which is a `void` expression.